# Apparent paradox about active and passive vector rotations

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Consider a single particle moving around the origin in a circle. If the particle's coordinates are $(x,y)$ at some time, it will reach $(x,-y)$ after some time as they lie on the circle.

The position vector of the particle is rotating about the origin. Now rotation of a vector by an angle $Z$ clockwise is equivalent is to rotating the coordinate axes anticlockwise by $Z$.

The components in the new axes rotated anticlockwise are given by : 
$$ x' = x\cos(Z) + y\sin(Z)$$
$$ y' = -x\sin(Z) + y\cos(Z)$$

These are also the component transformations if I rotate the vector clockwise and keep my axes the same.

The question is : By rotation of the axes , we cannot transform the vector $(x,y)$ into $(x,-y)$ since there is no angle $Z$ that satisfies the equations for this pair ( x and y not 0 ). But on rotating the vector we get $(x,-y)$. This seems to be a paradox. What am I missing here?

Comment: Whatever $+Z$ works with one case, $-Z$ should also work on the other. A rotation about an angle $+Z$ is equivalent to a coordinate transformation about an angle $-Z$.

Comment: $Z=\pi$ doesn't return (0,-1) for input (0,1)?

Comment: @KyleKanos it doesnt return (2,-3) for (2,3)

Comment: Try $Z\sim225.25^\circ$ for that case.

Comment: @KyleKanos cos(225.25) and sin(225.25) are negative. How can 2 negative quantities in the first equation add up to a positive quantity?

Comment: Hmm, seems python doesn't like to convert degrees to radians correctly.

Comment: @KyleKanos I got the answer in python, thanks anyway. I feel a little embarassed now.

Comment: I don't really see how you guys are getting a passive rotation that maps $(x,y)\rightarrow (x,-y)$. This is a reflection of the $y$ axis about the $x$ axis and therefore is not a rotation.

Comment: @Diracology Yes that is true. But for a given (x,y) there is an angle such that (x,y) goes to (x,-y). But that angle wont make the other vectors undergo the same transformation.

Comment: @Diracology Reflection maps all (x,y) to (x,-y) whereas the answer I got just converts (2,3) to (2,-3)

Comment: @cobra121 Exactly, but this holds only for a particular vector and that solves the paradox! I think this questions is worth of a detailed answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector Definitions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366702) by the same user.

Comment: -1. I do not think this is a worthwhile question. There is no paradox here, only confusion about what you are asking. As you have realised, there is a difference between mapping all points on the circle and mapping only one point.

Comment: @sammygerbil I agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you will not get the transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow(x,-y)$ by a rotation of the coordinate system (passive rotation) since this transformation actually corresponds to a reflection, namely
$$S=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&-1
\end{pmatrix},\tag1$$
which does not belong to the group of rotations in the plane, $SO(2)$.

On the other hand, by an active rotation $R(Z)$,
$$R(Z)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos Z&-\sin Z\\
\sin Z&\cos Z
\end{pmatrix},\tag2
$$
of a **definite** angle $Z$ you definitely can obtain the transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow(x,-y)$ for **some definite** vector $(x,y)$. The paradox you mentioned could be restated as following: How can a reflection matrix (in the passive view) be identified with a rotation matrix (in the active view)? There is no paradox though, since (1) and (2) are not supposed to be identified as operators. For example, both matrices
$$S=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&-1
\end{pmatrix},
\quad\mathrm{and}\quad 
R(3\pi/2)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
take the vector $(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)$ to $(1/\sqrt 2,-1/\sqrt 2)$, but $S$ takes $(0,1)$ to $(0,-1)$ whereas $R$ maps $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. The explicit representation of the operators above already shows they are different.